# Creating a function in Javascript and using it with a button

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get this button to run the function. I know I can get rid of 'function showWeb' in the Javascript and the code will be running fine, I am trying to get it to work so that I can use it as a function so I can make an instance of the object.

```
<button id='myBtn' onclick='showWeb()'>Open Modal</button>
<div id='myModal' class='modal'>
    <div class='modal-content'>
        <span class='close'>&times;</span>
        <p>$link</p>
    </div>
</div>      


<script>
        function showWeb(){
        // Get the modal
        var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

        // Get the button that opens the modal
        var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

        // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
        var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

        // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
        btn.onclick = function() {
            modal.style.display = "block";
        }

        // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
        span.onclick = function() {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }

        // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
        window.onclick = function(event) {
            if (event.target == modal) {
                modal.style.display = "none";
            }
        }

    }

</script>
```

Comment: `onclick='showWeb()'` should work. What is not working in your case?

Comment: Also event handlers should be outside this function, either put it in window.load or before `</body>

Comment: I'm not sure if your question is you're trying to call this function and test if this is working properly, You can check by adding alert() inside your created function, example:

alert('test button function');

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to get at, but please do consider that a `function` must only do a single task, it would be great if you refactored your code this way.

```js
function openModal() {
   var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
   modal.style.display = "block";
}

function closeModal() {
   var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
   modal.style.display = "none";
}

    window.onclick = function(event) {
        var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```

```html
<button id='myBtn' onclick='openModal()'>Open Modal</button>
<div id='myModal' class='modal'>
  <div class='modal-content'>
     <span class='close' onclick='closeModal()'>&times;</span>
    <p>$link</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This has been amazing help, I have just one more question if thats okay. Is there any way to close the modal without using it's ID.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you wouldn't want to retrieve the button *inside* the function.
Second of all, those onclick events are not being attached right (typo in this case)

what you want to do is:

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var btn = document.getElementById('myBtn');
var span = document.getElementsByClassName('close')[0];

btn.addEventListener('click', showModal());
span.addEventListener('click', hideModal());

function showModal() {
  modal.style.display = 'block';
};

function hideModal() {
  modal.style.display = 'none';
};

window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target != modal) { // needs to be anything but the modal, from what i can understand
    hideModal();
  }
});
```

```css
#myModal {
  display: none;
  background: #dd4535;
}
```

```html
<button id='myBtn'>Open Modal</button>
<div id='myModal' class='modal'>
    <div class='modal-content'>
        <span class='close'>&times;</span>
        <p>$link</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

No jquery this time, since it was obviously not well accepted. Just plain JS